# What can I do to improve closed question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309554/a-chess-board-representation-in-haskell

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309554/a-chess-board-representation-in-haskell was closed as not constructive.

I understand it as asking about the possibilities in Haskell of implementating a preferably-functional representation of a chess board with fast update and undo.

Now I could edit the question to ask that more directly, but I do not see how to do that without basically rewriting all the original text, so before I try something like that I wanted to ask for clarification on what improvements (if any) are really necessary for this specific question to be considered constructive and thus possibly reopened. Or should I instead try and ask a new question of my own?

Comment: Why do you want that reopened or improved? It has answers and the kind of substantial editing you suggest is likely to invalidate those.

Comment: @Oded, I do not find the answers very helpful. It having been closed may be the reason it does not have better answers. Moreover I would like to add an answer and cannot. About the substantial editing, I definitely very much want to avoid doing that, unless it is the only way to reopen and it is deemed preferable to a new similar question.

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question. Just leave that one alone. It is probably something that should just be deleted now.